# How to display symbol of Sri lankan rupees in Angularjs currency?

Tags: angularjs

I would like to display Sri lankan rupee's symbol for the currency. As we need to use currency to display price values in angular js.

Comment: is there a symbol for srilankan rupees?

Comment: I searched, there is no yet. I think that we have to use 'RS'

Answer (score 1):

By default it can be depend on the local server's time zone so either you have to change the time zone of your server or you can custom display your currency symbol, so you have two option, about second option you may use it like this :

```
<body ng-controller="indexCtrl">

    Input: <input type="text" ng-model="amount">
    <h3>{{ amount | currency : "RS : " }}</h3> // Your currency 
  OR
   <h3>{{ amount | currency : "₹ : " }}</h3> // Your currency symbol here it's temporary Indian currency symbol


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why would server's time zone affect anything that's being run completely on the browser? Or why would time zone affect currencies anyway?

Comment: Actually by default currency would take to show from local time zone with angular. But in you case you can show your custom as well like mentioned in above code.